# Create separate columns for key, value pairs contained in two columns of Spark Dataframe in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark/Scala and have been struggling with this problem. So far, I have looked into similar questions involving `explode` and `split`, but have had no luck so far.

Here is an example input Dataframe:

| id | attr_name | attr_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | name | James |
| 0 | hair_color | black |
| 1 | name | George |
| 1 | hair_color | black |
| 2 | name | Jack |
| 2 | hair_color | white |
| 2 | eye_color | blue |

And here is an example of the output I am looking for:

| id | name | hair_color | eye_color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | James | black |  |
| 1 | George | black |  |
| 2 | Jack | white | blue |

Any help would be appreciated here, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [pivot](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/RelationalGroupedDataset.html#pivot(pivotColumn:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,values:Seq%5BAny%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset). Your example becomes something like:

```
df.groupBy($"id")
  .pivot($"attr_name", Seq("hair_color", "eye_color"))
  .agg(first($"attr_value"))
```

Explicitly spelling out the values in the `attr_name` column will give you a decent performance improvement. I have to admit I'm not sure whether the `agg` is necessary, given that you have one element in each group.

Comment: This makes sense! How would I extend this if I have many attributes to the point where providing `Seq("name", "hair_color", "eye_color")` explicitly is not possible?

Comment: As an answer to the above comment, I was able to extend this simply by leaving out the Seq.